# Determine if one SKPhysics body is completely contained within another SKPhysics body

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm working on a tangrams game and I'm trying to determine when one triangular block is within a larger target template block. See an example [here](https://imageshack.com/i/f7e79cp).

I've looked at the documentation and on stackoverflow and I haven't been able to find an elegant way to determine if the physics body of one SKNode is completely contained within the physics body of another SkNode.

Comment: Triangles? You need a custom "triangle contains triangle" method then, no built-in support for that.

Comment: word thanks! Just wanted to double check!

Answer (score 0):

You should use two different SKPhysics bodies that are both the size of the target template block. One with an edge based physics body and one with a volume based physics body. If the triangular block is within the larger template block then the edge based physics body will not be in contact with the block but the volume based physics body will!

Check out the relevant [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW19)